# How to change cursor depending on element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a static website and I have my own custom cursor set I want to implement.

Default would be `cursor:url('*filepath*/normal.cur');`

then for text `cursor:url('*filepath*/textselect.cur');`

and for links `cursor:url('*filepath*/links.cur');`

while loading `cursor:url('*filepath*/loading.ani');`

how do I implement this properly to work?

Answer (score 2):

Give the element that you want the cursor changed a class and set the `:hover` property on it and change the cursor accordingly:

ex

```css
.div2:hover{
  cursor: url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/126124.png'), auto;
}
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aryjOz)

Answer (score 0):

you give all tages different ids and then add curser property on each element by using hover property

```
<a id="loading">Loading</a>
#loading {cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab;}
```